# Is there a way to limit which users response a discord bot reads after they have used a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am learning to write discord bots in python, so have settled on making a simple rock paper scissors bot. The way it currently works is the user types !RPS to start the game, and then has to type their choice, to which the bot replies with whether they have won or lost

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['rps', 'RPS'])
async def rock_paper_scissors(ctx):
    global gaming
    gaming = True
    gamer = ctx.message.author.name
    await ctx.send('Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global gaming
    global x
    x = 0
    while gaming == True:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        if x > 4:
            channel = message.channel
            await message.channel.send('Too Many Bad Responses, Shutting Down')
            gaming = False
            break 
        elif str.upper(message.content) not in ['ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSORS', 'R', 'P', 'S']:
            channel = message.channel
            await message.channel.send('Not A Valid Response')
            x = x + 1
            return
        else:
            response = random.choice(['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'])
            if str.upper(response) == str.upper(message.content):
                channel = message.channel
                await message.channel.send(f'I picked {response}, we drew!')
                gaming = False
            elif str.upper(response) == 'PAPER' and str.upper(message.content) in ['SCISSORS', 'S']:
                channel = message.channel
                await message.channel.send(f'I picked {response}, you won!')
                gaming = False
            elif str.upper(response) == 'PAPER' and str.upper(message.content) in ['ROCK', 'R']:
                channel = message.channel
                await message.channel.send(f'I picked {response}, I won!')
                gaming = False
            elif str.upper(response) == 'ROCK' and str.upper(message.content) in ['SCISSORS', 'S']:
                channel = message.channel
                await message.channel.send(f'I picked {response}, I won!')
                gaming = False
            elif str.upper(response) == 'ROCK' and str.upper(message.content) in ['PAPER', 'P']:
                channel = message.channel
                await message.channel.send(f'I picked {response}, you won!')
                gaming = False
            elif str.upper(response) == 'SCISSORS' and str.upper(message.content) in ['ROCK', 'R']:
                channel = message.channel
                await message.channel.send(f'I picked {response}, you won!')
                gaming = False
            elif str.upper(response) == 'SCISSORS' and str.upper(message.content) in ['PAPER', 'P']:
                channel = message.channel
                await message.channel.send(f'I picked {response}, I won!')
                gaming = False
            else:
                break
    gaming = False
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    x = 0
```

The issue I have is that if one user types !RPS, then a second user responds, the bot reads the second users response even though they are not playing the game. Is there any way to resolve this?

[Two Users Interacting With The Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI4fw.png)

I am planning on implementing a "leaderboard" for games won, so it would be very useful (and less confusing) if only the user who started the game (using the !RPS command) could submit their choice

Comment: The `while` loop under `gaming == True` has not effect, actually, since the loop will always exit after the first iteration, no matter which conditions are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `rock_paper_scissors()` function, you can use the [`Bot.wait_for()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for). You can create a check, to verify that the member who responds is the same who invoked the command.

```py
@bot.command(aliases = ['rps', 'RPS'])
async def rock_paper_scissors(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors")
    try:
        choice = await bot.wait_for(
            "message",
            timeout=60.0
            check=lambda msg: msg.author == ctx.author
        )
        choice = choice.lower().strip()[0]
        if choice not in ["r", "p", "s"]:
            await ctx.channel.send("Invalid selection")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        return
    await check_result(choice)

async def check_result(user_choice):
    bot_choice = random.choice(["r", "p", "s"])
    await ctx.channel.send(f"User selected {user_choice}\nBot selected {bot_choice}")
    if bot_choice == user_choice:
        await ctx.channel.send("Result: Tie")
    elif (bot_choice, user_choice) in (("r", "s"), ("p", "r"), ("s", "p")):
        await ctx.channel.send("Result: Bot is victorious")
    elif (user_choice, bot_choice) in (("r", "s"), ("p", "r"), ("s", "p"):
        await ctx.channel.send("Result: User is victorious")
```

Inside the `try` clause, the bot waits for an `on_message()` event, times out (raises `asyncio.TimeoutError`) after 60.0 seconds, and checks that the message author is the same user who invoked the `rock_paper_scissors` command.

After the `try`/`except` statements would be the code which randomizes the bot's selection as well as checks for the result of the two selections. (Your code which determines the result may vary from mine; I just wrote my approach so the entirety of the code sample makes sense.)

Comment: Sorry I think I'm slightly confused as to where to put the bot selection/check loop, currently I have them as two separate loops (The first bot.command and the second bot.event). To implement this solution do I have to take the second checking loop out of it's own event and put it all together as one?

Comment: @BenHaynes You don't need the `on_message()` event reference, and this `rock_paper_scissors()` replaces the old `rock_paper_scissors()`. The `wait_for()` in the new code waits for an `on_message()` event, effectively replacing the `on_message()` event reference in the old code.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! A bit of wrangling and I got it to work with your solution, makes it much cleaner too to do it that way